# removing pre-existing "Preload" attribute with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes, preload

A SandVox template I am implementing with automatically adds in "Preload" attribute to the video and audio tags.

This is what SandVox puts in when you drag a video/audio into the template:
...
...

I'm using a popcorn.js-based script that can sync video and audio tags by playhead but it can only work without the Preload attribute in the tags. Is there a way to "conveniently" disable the attribute even if it's already written in the video/audio tags? I tried with .removeAttr () and several other related scripts but it won't work. I'm not sure if I'm on the right direction.

This is what I put in Header:

---

$('#video').removeAttr('preload');                                          

                                $('#audio').removeAttr('preload');

---

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're in the right direction. $(element).removeAttr('someAttr') is correct. The attribute is likely being added after your code, or you're not targeting the correct element.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the reply. There was a part in my post that got omitted, actually. When I drag a QT to the template, it automatically puts in preload="none" in the video tag, which is why I wanted to find out if I could remove the attribute by adding .removeAttr () in the Header. I was also trying to see if there's a way to remove the specific script that does that, but that's deeper into programming and I'm not familiar with that. Thanks!

Comment: To be quite honest, I'm not familiar with SandVox templates. However, I am quite certain that if you do have access to scripts within your site, if you load a script with the `removeAttr()` call `last`, the attributes will be removed. However, if you don't have access to scripts/to add the last script on document load, this wouldn't do you any good. Best of luck though!